# I want to display string into row by row

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I want to display characters of a string in separate rows.

Example:
Given a string `ORACLE`, I want to get output as

```
O 
R
A
C
L
E
```

Comment: what sql are you using ? PL Sql Oracle ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're using Oracle's SQL, you could query the word from `dual`, connect it by level and use the level to extract a character with `substr`:

```
SELECT     SUBSTR(word, LEVEL, 1)
FROM       (SELECT 'oracle' AS word 
            FROM   DUAL)
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH(word)
```

Answer (score -2):

There are various techniques for the same, but rather than processing it on server side to increase performance, ensure the same at client end using css as follows:

```
 p{word-spacing: 1px;}
```

Hope this helps.